# rails basic polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

i'm trying to create a polymorphic relationship between votes can be submitted by users and apply to articles.  my code

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :voteable_id, :voteable_type
  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true  
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :voteable
end
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :voteable
end

<Vote id: 1, value: 1, created_at: "2012-07-27 03:13:14", updated_at: "2012-07-27 03:13:14", voteable_id: nil, voteable_type: nil>
```

From looking at the rails documentation via http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

I feel that my code is set correctly but i'm having a bit of trouble triggering it correctly, ie, how do I actually create a vote object with a properly define relationship to either an article or user?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work, I was setting the `voteable_type` attribute incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Is votable_type is string?
Next example should work correctly..

```
  @user.votes.new :value => 1
  @user.save
```

.

Comment: yes, above is correct thanks.  i wasn't naming the .votes correctly but i figured it out.  polym is pretty useful